# Symfony4 - Process - Command Could not open input file bin/console

Tags: php, symfony, command-line-interface

I'm building a symfony4 webapp.
I have a command that I can run like a charm directly in cli :

```
php bin/console app:analysis-file 4
```

But when I try to `exec` if directly from a `Controller` via :

```
$process = new Process('php bin/console app:analysis-file '. 
$bankStatement->getId());
$process->run();
```

Then `$process->getOutput()` return "`Could not open input file bin/console`".

This is the `Command` `Class` :

```
class AnalysisFileCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('app:analysis-file')
            ->addArgument('file_id', InputArgument::REQUIRED);
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $entityManager = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
        $bankStatement = $entityManager->getRepository(BankStatement::class)->find($input->getArgument("file_id"));
        $bankStatement->setStatus(BankStatement::ANALYZING);
        $entityManager->persist($bankStatement);
        $entityManager->flush();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would guess that the current working directory does not match your project root. Because of that, relative path `bin/console` does not exist.

You have 2 ways to solve this:

1. Set the current working directory:

   ```
   $kernel = ...; // Get instance of your Kernel
   $process = new Process('php bin/console app:analysis-file ');
   $process->setWorkingDirectory($kernel->getProjectDir());
   $bankStatement->getId());
   $process->run();
   ```
2. Invoke  the command via Symfony Command call, which is described in [official docs article](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console/command_in_controller.html)

Have in mind that #2 has a slight overhead (as described in the article)

Hope this helps...

Comment: Aaaaaaaand.... it worked perfectly. Shame on me to forget the working directory. Anyway for those looking how to get instance of kernel : `$this->container->get('kernel');` Thank you !

Comment: Solution #2 doesn't run the command asynchronously though.